# Execute ajax call only once

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am loading facebook likebox onscroll. but everytime I scroll up/down the ajax is being fired. I want ajax to fire only once. Here is my code:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery(window).scroll(function() { 
        var scroll = jQuery(window).scrollTop();

        if (scroll <= 770) {
      jQuery.get('ajax/facebook.html', function(data) { jQuery('.fblikeajax').html(data);});
        }

    }); 
});
```

Comment: look at this example : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9758527/jquery-callback-on-end-of-page-scroll

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use JQuery's `on()` and `off()`

```
$(document).on("scroll", scrollcheck);

var scrollcheck = function () {
    var scroll = jQuery(window).scrollTop();
    if (scroll <= 770) {
        jQuery.get('ajax/facebook.html', function (data) {
            jQuery('.fblikeajax').html(data);
        });
        $(document).off("scroll", scrollcheck);
    }
}
```

Comment: `one` will only fire once, but that doesn't mean your `if` statement passes. For click events etc. you could use `one`

Answer (score 1):

You could add in a variable that checks if the ajax has been fired:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    var ajax_fired = false;
    jQuery(window).scroll(function() { 
        var scroll = jQuery(window).scrollTop();

        if ((scroll <= 770) && !ajax_fired) {
            ajax_fired = true;
            jQuery.get('ajax/facebook.html', function(data) {
                jQuery('.fblikeajax').html(data);

            });
        }

    }); 
});
```

Comment: This still has the potential to fire off requests until the first response is received and changes the `ajax_fired` flag.

Answer (score 0):

Unbind the event listener after it fires:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    var scrollHandler = function() { 
        var scroll = jQuery(window).scrollTop();

        if (scroll <= 770) {
      jQuery.get('ajax/facebook.html', function(data) { jQuery('.fblikeajax').html(data);});
        }
        $(window).unbind('scroll', scrollHandler);
    }
    jQuery(window).scroll(scrollHandler); 
});
```

I haven't tested that code, but it should be pretty close.