# Ajax scroll bar down keep firing ajax request after full records loaded

Tags: javascript, ajax, asp.net-mvc-3, jquery

I am using this code to load ajax content in my MVC3 app, but problem is when I scroll down and it loads all pages, then ajax request fire again for two times to load the records. I have set a message to show up when the Model== null or Model.Count() == 0 and this message loads twice after full records.
my JS code is:

```
 var page = 0;
    var _inCallback = false;
    function loadProducts() {
        if (page > -1 && !_inCallback) {
            _inCallback = true;
            page++;
            $('div#loading').html('<p><img src="/Content/ajax-loader.gif"></p>');
            $.get("/Sort/All/" + page, function (data) {
                if (data != '') {
                    $("#productList").append(data);
                }
                if( page > 14 )  {
                $(window).off("scroll");
                $('div#loading').empty();
           } else {
                _inCallback = false;
           }
                $('div#loading').empty();
           });
        }
    }
    var dcList = true;
    $(window).scroll(function () {
        if ($(window).scrollTop()  >= ($(document).height() - $(window).height())*0.95) {
            loadProducts();
        }
    });
```

Note: in above code 14 are total pages

My controller is:

```
                var pageno = page ?? 0;
                if (Request.IsAjaxRequest())
                {
                    return PartialView("_cpus", _data.GetALLPaginatedProducts(pageno ));
                }
                return View("Index", _data.GetALLProducts());
```

Please see and tell me where I am doing wrong.

Any Help would be highly appreciable.

Thanks and Regards

Comment: anyone please, I need help. Thanks

Comment: Try the answer to this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17495109/execute-ajax-call-only-once/17495191#comment25430669_17495191